# Save measurement data into Database or Filesystem

Tags: database, api, file, filesystems, bigdata

We are currently developing a tool to count wildlife passing through defined areas. The gadget that automatically counts the animals will be sending data (weather, # of animals passing etc.) in a 5 minute interval via HTTP to our API. There will be hundreds of these measurement stations and it should be scalable.

Now the question arised whether to use a filesystem or a RDBMS to save this data.

Pro DB

- save exact time and date when the entry was created
- directly related to area# via indexed key

Pro Filesystem

- Collecting data is not as resource intensive since for every API call only 1 line will be appended to the file

Properties of the data:

- only related to 1 DB entry (the area #)
- the measurement stations are in remote areas we have to account for outages

What will be done with the data

- Give a overview over timeperiods per area#
- act as a early warning system if the # of animals is surprisingly low/high

  - Probably by using a cronjob and comparing to simliar data

We are thinking to chose a RDBMS to save the data but I am worried that after millions of entries the DB will slow down and eventually stop working. This question was [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051226/what-should-be-the-better-solution-for-store-and-manage-big-data) where 360M entries is not really considered "big data" so I'm not quite sure about my task either.

Should we chose [these recommended techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6513724/2306363) (MongoDB ...) or can this task be handled by PostgreSQL or MySQL?

Comment: This is pretty subjective and I suspect you will get dinged for that.  IMO, either approach will work fine.  The thing you should consider is a queueing architecture where the messages are sent later if the field units, or server, is offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created such a system for marine boyes. The devices sends data over GPRS / iridum using HTTP or raw tcp sockets (to minimize bandwidth).

- The recieving server stores the data in a db-table, with data provided and timestamp.
- The data is then parsed and records are created in another table.
- The devices can also request UTC-time from the server, thus not needing a RTC.

Before any storage is made to the "raw" table, a row is appended to a text-file. This is puerely for logging or being able to recover from database downtime.

As for database type, I'd recommend regular RDBMS. Define markers for your data. We use 4-digit codes that gives headroom for 10000 types of measure values.